# What is the purpose of the tilde operator when used to append the paste0() function in R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, rename

I am unsure as to how exactly the following line of code works, given that without the tilde:

```
betterLifeIndicators <- betterLifeIndicators |>   
rename_with(paste0(.x, ")"))
```

it doesn't work, citing that the object '.x' is not found. Yet when adding the tilde in front of paste0:

```
betterLifeIndicators <- betterLifeIndicators |>   
rename_with(~paste0(.x, ")"))
```

it works perfectly. I am quite new to R and I am struggling to understand the mechanism at work here. I am unsure as to how that whole line:

```
rename_with(~paste0(.x, ")"))
```

is achieving its purpose (appending a parenthesis to every column name in a data.frame).

This is a flaw in my understanding of R, but I would appreciate any help with understanding this whole situation since I would hate to move forward with my project while leaving such a hole in my understanding of the language.

Comment: The tilde is a way to define lambda functions/anonymous functions within the tidyverse package eg `~paste0(.x)` is similar to `function(.x)paste0(.x)` or even `\(.x)paste0(.x)`. For example `map_dbl(1:3, ~.x^2)` will be similar to `map_dbl(1:3, function(i) i^2)` or if you want to use the `.x` you do `map_dbl(1:3, function(.x).x^2)` or short hand `map_dbl(1:3, \(x)x^2)`. Notice that the tilde only works within the tidyverse package. eg `sapply(1:3, ~.x^2)` will not work yet `sapply(1:3, \(.x).x^2)` or even `sapply(1:3, function(.x).x^2)` will work

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. If I am understanding correctly, the tilde is defining paste0 as an anonymous function. What is the purpose of .x in this whole thing?

Comment: The `.x` is the default defined parameter. Note that for any function, there should be a parameter definition. so if you use `~` to define the lambda function, then your parameters will be `.x,.y` depending as to whether the function takes in 1 parameter or 2 parameters. in your case, `rename_with` only takes in the names, and will rename them accordingly, so `.x` here stands for the `names` of the dataframe being passed in.

Comment: So then what that line is doing is, rename_with() takes all the column names in my dataframe, and renaming them according to my paste0() function, which is a lambda function where the .x parameter is the name of the column and the y parameter is the appendix ")" I want to add?

Comment: There is no y parameter. simply put your function is doing this: `names(betterLifeIndicators) <- paste0(names(betterLifeIndicators), ")")`. Do you understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, this is some tidyverse jungle, but you can try to think about it like so:

In standard R there is a type of object called "formula" which is created with a tilde like so:

```
f <- ~ anythinig + can + be + here + paste(1, 2, 3)
```

We can check what is the class of this object and we get:

```
> class(f)
[1] formula
```

Then, `rename_with()` is a function. It needs to be passed at least 2 arguments: 1) a data.frame, 2) a function that renames the columns:

```
> rename_with(iris, toupper)
SEPAL.LENGTH SEPAL.WIDTH PETAL.LENGTH PETAL.WIDTH SPECIES
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

In R functions can choose what to do with their arguments. We can try to inspect what this particular function does:

```
> rename_with
function (.data, .fn, .cols = everything(), ...) 
{
    UseMethod("rename_with")
}
<bytecode: 0x7faad65f8510>
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Not that useful, it tells us that this function is a generic function, the real body of it is hidden in some other place. We can find it here:

```
> dplyr:::rename_with.data.frame
function (.data, .fn, .cols = everything(), ...) 
{
    .fn <- as_function(.fn)
    cols <- tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(.cols), .data, allow_rename = FALSE)
    names <- names(.data)
...
```

Now we see that the first step it does to the second argument (.fn) is transform it into a function with `as_function(.fn)`.

This `as_function()` function is in another tidyverse package - "rlang" and we can find it there:

```
> rlang::as_function
function (x, env = global_env(), ..., arg = caller_arg(x), call = caller_env()) 
{
    check_dots_empty0(...)
    if (is_function(x)) {
        return(x)
    }
    if (is_quosure(x)) {
        mask <- eval_tidy(call2(environment), env = quo_get_env(x))
        fn <- new_function(pairlist2(... = ), quo_get_expr(x), mask)
        return(fn)
    }
    if (is_formula(x)) {
        if (length(x) > 2) {
...
```

The relevant part for us is this `is_formula` call in the end of the part of output I showed. So basically `rename_with` has some clever(?) way to turn a formula into a function. But you can achieve the same thing by passing your own function:

```
iris |> rename_with(function(x) paste0(x, ")"))

  Sepal.Length) Sepal.Width) Petal.Length) Petal.Width) Species)
1           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2   setosa
2           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2   setosa
3           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2   setosa
4           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2   setosa
5           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2   setosa
6           5.4          3.9           1.7          0.4   setosa
```

The approach with tilde (creating a formula that is then turned into a function within `rename_with`) is just some syntax sugar. Under the hood the code then turns this formula into a function.

And your first approach:

```
betterLifeIndicators <- betterLifeIndicators |>   
rename_with(paste0(.x, ")"))
```

didn't work, because in your call the argument `paste0(.x, ")")` is not yet in a final form - it needs to be evaluated, R interpreter tries to evaluate this statement first but fails to find `.x` and shows you an error.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. The only part of the puzzle I am now missing would be understanding how passing our own function tells R that "x" is equal to the column name; in other words, why does the paste0(x) need a function(x)? Isn't paste0() a function that can behave as the second argument of "rename_with"?

Comment: `paste0` is a function. `paste0()` is a function call that has to be evaluated and turned into result. The same way `sum` is a function, but `sum(3,4)` is `7`. You can pass the `paste0` function (without the call), but by default it will not append anything: `rename_with(iris, paste0)`. To make it append you can create a separate function first: `mypaste <- function(x) paste0(x, ")")`, and then pass it `rename_with(iris, mypaste)`. And you also can create the function in-place: `rename_with(iris, function(x) paste0(x, ")"))`. Does this help?

Comment: This explanation is very helpful indeed. I see now that my mistake was not understanding the correct way to create functions in R. The only thing I am still unsure about is, how does x become the column name (given that it is not specified anywhere as with other languages)?

Comment: Basically, in other words, you need to pass a WAY to transform the columns. And in R this is a function - a thing that does something. When you call a function you get an object - but an object cannot be used to make transformations on your column names.

Comment: It's really simple. Consider this function: `bang <- function(x) paste0(x, "!")`. This function works on anything, not just column names. Here: `bang(c("a", "b"))`. So this is a method to transform things. When you pass this method to `rename_with()` that `rename_with()` function simply applies this transformation to the columns of the data. That's it. `x` is a general placeholder for the function argument, the same way `sum(x)` is.

Comment: Ah so "x" in this scenario is just a placeholder. We create function(x), make that function paste0(x, ")") and rename_with applies to all columns since it is defaulted to do just that. Thank you very much for your time, this has truly helped me better understand R.